# Python tkinter, tkinter.askdirectory() returns the initial default directory when user hits 'cancel' or X out, or Esc the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, filedialog

No matter what I do, `tkinter.filedialog.askdirectory()` returns the initial default (current directory) when the `Cancel` button, or the `X` close button on the window, or if the user selects `Esc`. I tried coding the option for an initial directory to `C:\`, rather than `E:\` where the script is saved, to try to control this. However, if `Cancel`, `X`, or `Esc` is selected, it still returns `E:\`.  I also tried adding the `root.protocol` to force the `X` to close the entire program, but it did not change the behavior. I initialized the directory with an empty string, which also had no effect. All the documentation, and question/answers I find, simply state that it should return an empty string in these cases. I need this to be true! I cannot see what is wrong here; thanks in advance for any advice. The only hint I have - is I am unsure how tkinter message and file dialogs use, or if they use, the root window. I think this is where I may be losing control...??

I am on Windows 10, using Python 3.7.0.

Here is a toy example of what I have:

```
import os
import tkinter
import tkinter.filedialog as tkf

class Directory(tkinter.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
            
        self.root = tkinter.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.root.quit())
        self.root.withdraw()

        self.directory = ""
        
       
    def GetDirectory(self):
        self.directory = os.path.abspath(tkf.askdirectory(master = self.root, initialdir = 'C:\\', title = "Select your Source directory")) 
        print('type directory', type(self.directory), self.directory=="", self.directory)
      
        return self.directory

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = Directory()
    Directory.GetDirectory(app)

Output after hitting cancel, Esc, or X:

type directory <class 'str'> False E:\
```

Comment: can u highlight the output u get too? vs the output u expect ?

Comment: Thanks, Cool Cloud, I have added the output (print statement).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cause of your problem is you add [`os.path.abspath()`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/os.path.html#os.path.abspath) in your `askdirectory`.

> os.path.abspath():Return a normalized absolutized version of the pathname path

Even though it will return `""` when you cancel or press "X", but `os.path.abspath("")` would return the absolute path of current folder.

```
self.directory = tkf.askdirectory(master=self.root, initialdir='C:\\', title="Select your Source directory")
```

This just return the absolute path of the folder you select.And when you select nothing, it will return `""`.

Comment: Excellent!  Thank you - that lesson will stick with me. :)