# Python - filedialog.askdirectory won't recognize initialdir of local drive

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to get the second filedialog call in my script to open to my local C drive, but it will only open the first call's initialdir, which is a UNC path.  (Both are stored in different variables).

1:  Is the following syntax correct, and is there anything I need to do to force the code to use the second call's initialdir?

```
filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=r"C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop",title='Please select a directory')
```

2:  Also, can you have a variable in the initialdir, like this?

```
filedialog.askdirectory(initialdir=r"C:\\Users\\User1\\"+variable+"\UserFolder1",title='Please select a directory')
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63221952/python-tkinter-tkinter-askdirectory-returns-the-initial-default-directory-whe

Comment: Thanks for the link!  I'm not sure if it helps.  I was not able to get it to work.  I'm not sure what the root window is or if I have to use it to get my second dialog to work.